# scrollTop() returns 0 if there is a doctype

Tags: javascript, html

In Firefox 39.0 and IE 11, if a HTML5 document has a doctype `<!doctype html>`, `document.body.scrollTop` will always return `0`.
For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample page</title>
</head>

<body>
    Aliquip summis doctrina admodum, pariatur praesentibus non laboris aut an eram...
    <script>
       window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
          console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above always logs 0 in the console when you scroll, but if you remove the `doctype`, it returns, as expected, the distance from the top the body has been scrolled.
Note that it works with or without a doctype in Chrome.

I would rather not remove the doctype, and am wondering why it does this, and if there is a way around it?

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: @Huangism oh goodness... I googled it, but never found out that `document.body.scrollTop` was depreciated. I guess I need to work on my google skills:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: `document.documentElement.scrollTop.`

`document.body.scrollTop` is deprecated.

If you need it to be browser specific, you can

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') !== -1){
    scrollTo(document.documentElement, y, 200);
}else{
    scrollTo(document.body, y, 200);
}
```

Comment: This is a Chrome bug: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Oct/0287.html

Comment: thanks a lot :D I was told to use document.body, I guess he didn't know it was depreciated either